# Indexing for multiple ORDER BY in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, mysql-8.0, order-by

I feel like I have optimized this query to the best of my ability, but it is still slow (usually takes 0.5s - 2s in development).
It seems like the ORDER BY is the culprit, as when I get rid of it, it takes less than 20ms.

```
select
  products.*
from
  products
  inner join product_section on product_section.product_id = products.id
  and product_section.section_id in (1)
  inner join category_product on category_product.product_id = products.id
  and category_product.category_id = 83
  inner join images on images.product_id = products.id
  and images.is_featured = 1
where
  products.niche_id = 1
  and products.advertiser_main_site_epc >= 1
order by
  products.advertiser_status desc,
  products.instock desc,
  products.random_number asc,
  products.advertiser_main_site_epc desc,
  products.id desc
limit
  90
```

The EXPLAIN output says it's using filesort.

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | images |  | index | product_id | product_id | 7 |  | 111062 | 10.00 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | category_product |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,product_id,category_product_category_id_idx | PRIMARY | 8 | const,dfsystem.images.product_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | products |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,idx_products_niche_id_advertiser_main_site_epc | PRIMARY | 4 | dfsystem.images.product_id | 1 | 50.00 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | product_section |  | eq_ref | PRIMARY,section_id | PRIMARY | 8 | dfsystem.images.product_id,const | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

I have added an index on the 'products' table in an attempt to speed up the ORDER BY:

`KEY idx_products_niche_id_advertiser_main_site_epc (niche_id,advertiser_main_site_epc DESC,advertiser_status DESC,instock DESC,random_number,id DESC)`

However, it doesn't seem to be chosen by the optimizer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the tables.  It _seems_ that you have 4 tables, each with `PRIMARY KEY(prodicut_id)` instead of having a single table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index will not be able to avoid the ordering operation. The order of columns are incorrect. Here are the correct ones by the PawSQL tool we build,

```
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX2074096603 ON products(niche_id,advertiser_status DESC,instock DESC,random_number,advertiser_main_site_epc DESC, id DESC);
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX0475371273 ON images(is_featured,product_id);
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX1365940357 ON category_product(category_id,product_id);
CREATE INDEX PAW_IDX1720780105 ON product_section(section_id,product_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the only useful index for `products`:

```
INDEX(niche_id, advertiser_main_site_epc) -- in this order
```

That handles the `WHERE`.  Since it ends with a range test, it can't continue into doing the `ORDER`.